# Not getting response Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, callback

I am trying to get the response from sendResponse to chrome.runtime.sendMessage, but its always showing undefined, below is my code:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(JSON.stringify(contact), function(response) {
    console.log('Response: ', response); // This is showing undefined
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
   contact.addContact(request, function() {
      sendResponse({success: 'true'});
   });
});
```

So when I pass sendResponse({success: true}) that should be received in callback on chrome.runtime.sendMessage but instead of that its showing undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is probably caused by `contact.addContact` being asynchronous. This means that the listener ends before `sendResponse` is called. Returning `true` from the listener like this should fix it:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
   contact.addContact(request, function() {
      sendResponse({success: 'true'});
   });
   return true;
});
```

From the [documentation of chrome.runtime.onMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage):

> **sendResponse**:
>
> Function to call (at most once) when you have a response. The argument
>   should be any JSON-ifiable object. If you have
>   more than one onMessage listener in the same document, then only one
>   may send a response. ***This function becomes invalid when the event
>   listener returns, unless you return true from the event listener*** to
>   indicate you wish to send a response asynchronously (this will keep
>   the message channel open to the other end until sendResponse is
>   called).

Comment: Yes that worked, thanks a lot... :)